# BrainTreepayment Fatal Error Magento Community 1.8.1

Tags: php, payment, magento-1.8, braintree

I just installed the Braintree payment gateway on my store

But each time I click on the "CHECKOUT" button i get this:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Braintree_Configuration' not found in /public_html/app/code/local/Braintree/Payments/Model/Paymentmethod.php on line 917.
```

The Code snippet is :

```
917       Braintree_Configuration::environment($this->getConfigData('environment', $storeId));
918       Braintree_Configuration::merchantId($this->getConfigData('merchant_id', $storeId));
919       Braintree_Configuration::publicKey($this->getConfigData('public_key', $storeId));
920       Braintree_Configuration::privateKey($this->getConfigData('private_key', $storeId));
          $this->_merchantAccountId = $this->getConfigData('merchant_account_id', $storeId);
          $this->_useVault = $this->getConfigData('use_vault', $storeId);
          $this->_allowDuplicates = $this->getConfigData('duplicate_card', $storeId);       
    }
```

Been on this for 24 hours together with the Braintree tech support and no resolution yet. Any insights into the problem will be deeply appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: aren't you missing to import the Braintree_Configuration class?

Answer (score 2):

<sub>I work at Braintree. It looks like we already got back to you and solved your problem, but I'll post this here for anyone else who runs into the same issue. You can also always [reach our support team directly](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

This error is caused by an installation problem with the Magento Plugin. Uninstalling and reinstalling fixes it.

We have both [installation instructions](https://support.braintreepayments.com/customer/portal/articles/1550471-magento-installation) and [troubleshooting tips](https://support.braintreepayments.com/customer/portal/articles/1550471-magento-installation) for Magento available on our support pages.